# VS cannot find ntddk.h, wdf.h or fwpmk.h

Tags: windows, visual-studio, driver, kmdf, windows-driver

I am working on a new KMDF driver with the help of ChatGPT and my initial problem is that visual studio cannot find ntddk.h, wdf.h or fwpmk.h. I have both the windows SDK and WDK installed.

No need to share my code because it's the includes that are the problem. Also the project is the default empty KMDF project.